# Have there been any efforts to port some of Rails' View Helpers to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

It would be great to have helpers like `linkTo()`, `truncate()`, and `pluralize()` in Javascript. Have there been any efforts to port some or all of Rails' view helpers to Javascript?

Comment: Myself, I’d love to see the functions for formatting numbers (with delimiters or like “55.2M”)

Answer (score 2):

If you just need one or two, you can find [snippets for pluralize and singularize](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3205) or [another for truncating](http://marcada.ms/2010/02/truncating-a-string-in-javascript/).

And actually, there's now a javascript library that handles a lot of the syntactic sugar:

[Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/api/String/parameterize)

Like I said in my original post, no need to include a whole library if you only want one or two of them or can manage to just use the Rails helpers, but the option to have them is out there.

Comment: `truncate` and `pluralize` are probably bad examples if you want to argue they would hurt load time significantly. Those are pretty tiny, unless of course we are assuming there’s also a large embedded list of known irregular plurals… in which case, we’re in agreement